# How can I detect if a device token is obsolete?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I have a big database with devices token.

I guess a lot of my base are obsolete token.

How can I detect if a device token is obsolete?

Thank you.

Comment: Always keep the updated token against single user.

Comment: Ok, I have to work with my database and not with the device token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this exact reason, Apple provides a feed back service. You should set up a batch process or stored procedure in your database which periodically fetches invalid tokens and removes or mark  as inactive in the database.

[APNS : Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)